# Using a PL/SQL stored procedure in Crystal Report command object

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I'd like to call a stored procedure from a crystal report command object using an Oracle direct connection. The stored procedure takes a refcursor and some parameters that can be passed from the report, but I'm not sure what the syntax should look like.

For simplicity, feel free to pretend that the stored procedure only takes a refcursor and nothing else. What should the syntax look like? I assume I need to declare the refcursor, call the SP, and then return the cursor.

I'm pretty unfamiliar with this stuff though, and I'm not actually sure how to return the cursor. I figure the first bit would look like:

```
VARIABLE Cursor refcursor

declare
begin 
MYSTOREDPROCEDURE(:Cursor);
end;
/
```

I'm not sure how to then return the cursor for Crystal Reports to use (2008/2011). I hope this was enough information.

Comment: Please don't use a stored-procedure with Crystal Reports.  Its performance is not likely to be any better than 'regular' query, but the maintenance effort is *significantly* higher.  In my 18 years of working with Crystal Reports, I've never needed to use one--and I've seen a LOT of reports.

Comment: Actually, having a more modular stored procedure seems much more maintainable than a 1000+ line command object. And long story short, it's something I need to do one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a stored procedure from a `command`.  You need to add it to the report in the same manner as you add a table (in the database expert).  Moreover, the SP needs to be built a certain way to work with CR; specifically, it needs to return a `REF CURSOR`.

[Example.](http://www.pdssoftware.com/newsletter/mar07/page6.htm)

Comment: You definitely can with an ODBC connection (I've got that set up and working). Is it different for an Oracle direct connection?

Comment: Really?  What is the ODBC syntax?  The few times that I've experimented with the native, Oracle connection, I've used the syntax in the example.  Color me surprised...

Comment: {Call STORED_PROCEDURE('Parameters','More Parameters')}